# Powershell replace is duplicating results

Tags: powershell, replace

I have a simple script that is suppose to find text and if the right conditions are met, it will replace the text:

```
foreach ($line in $file){
$line.replace("â‡","+") | Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
if ($line -eq "â‡RECORD_IDENTIFIER:"){
    $line.replace("â‡RECORD_IDENTIFIER:","+RECORD_IDENTIFIER: A") | Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
}
if ($line -eq "â‡END_TAG"){
    $line.replace("â‡END_TAG","+END_TAG;") | Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
}
```

but the result is this:

```
+START_TAG:
+DATA_FILE_(DATE/TIME):2017-02-13T13:44:44.489-08:00
+RECORD_IDENTIFIER:
+RECORD_IDENTIFIER: A
+CLIENT_NUM:8802
+SOLOMON_ID:TRUG01
```

I only want it to produce one RECORD_IDENTIFIER.

Comment: You have `$line.replace("â‡","+")`  which runs for the record line. Then your if would also fire the for record identifier. Since the `$line` is still `â‡RECORD_IDENTIFIER:`

Comment: Okay, I tried something like this:

`foreach ($line in $file){
    $line.replace("â‡","+") | Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
    if ($line -eq "+RECORD_IDENTIFIER:"){
        $line.replace("+RECORD_IDENTIFIER:","+RECORD_IDENTIFIER: A") | Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
    }
    if ($line -eq "+END_TAG"){
        $line.replace("+END_TAG","+END_TAG;") | Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
    }
}`

....but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

This is where you need to discover the `Switch` operator. I think it's an operator, maybe a cmdlet? Whatever it is, its what you need! What it does is compare the current iteration of a collection against multiple cases, and applies the cases that match. For example:

```
Switch ($file) {

    "â‡RECORD_IDENTIFIER:" {
        $_.Replace("â‡RECORD_IDENTIFIER:", "+RECORD_IDENTIFIER: A") |
            Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
        Continue
    }

    "â‡END_TAG" { 
        $_.Replace("â‡END_TAG", "+END_TAG;") |
            Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
        Continue
    }

    default {
        $_.Replace("â‡", "+") |
            Out-File -FilePath $destination -Append
    }

}
```

The `Continue` commands tell the loop to move to the next item, so if it matches the first case it will do your replace, output it to file, and then move to the next line. If it does not match the first case it tries the second, and if it matches it will do the replace for that, output to file, and move to the next line. If it doesn't match either of the first two cases it reaches the `default` line, and everything has that scriptblock applied to it, so anything that didn't match the first two cases has the `replace("â‡","+")` performed, and output to file.

Comment: This method worked flawlessly for a simpler text file, I created a text file like:

<code>
blue
orange
yellow
</code>

using this code:


switch ($testFile){                
    “blue” {$_.replace("blue","green") | Out-File -FilePath "\\a1-gcs-snf-001\DataFeeds\TrueGreen\test_modified.txt" -Append; continue}
    default {$_ | Out-File -FilePath "\\a1-gcs-snf-001\DataFeeds\TrueGreen\test_modified.txt" -Append}
}


It switched `blue` to `green` no problem. 

When I run it for my big text file, none of the replaces seem to work.

Comment: i got it to work! Something weird happened with the unicode when I copy pasted it... Thank you!